# What is this in my air duct

Tags: hvac

I started hearing a whistling sound coming out from the return vent for the air conditioner. So   I pulled out the filter to inspect it and noticed there was something odd inside the duct. It looks like trash and wasn’t sure if I should remove it.

The duct goes straight up the package unit on the roof.

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like a piece of tile or drop-ceiling panel...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "trash".   This is exactly why I don't like flexible air ducts lines and I only use them if I absolutely have to.

Couple of things:

- this fell between connections.  Connections should be sealed/taped.   That isn't a good sign.
- anything in the way of your line will decrease effeciency.
- might just be the picture... but your line looks dirty.   I don't often say that but it needs a cleaning.   This is another reason why flex lines aren't as good.  They are dust collectors.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a set of tools used to pry up moldings and such.